# How to write this query in LINQ c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, subquery

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM installment WHERE SellorderID = (";
$sql .= "SELECT ID FROM sellorder WHERE ShopID = (";
$sql .= "SELECT ID FROM shop WHERE Number = $shopno)) AND Received = 0";
```

The `$shopno` is parameter of the function.

Comment: Could you tidy up the formatting of the question please.

Comment: how does the model looks like? can you specify the entity framework version? final question, what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from i in Installment
join so in SellOrder 
   on i.SellOrderId equals so.ID
join sh in Shop
   on so.ShopId equals sh.Id
where sh.Number == $shopno && i.Received == 0
select i
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of an open ended question.
Is your target solution wanting to use LinqToSql, Entity framework, local data sources, or ...??

I'd suggest you have a look at this guide to understand a bit more about LinqToSql in C#.

[Simple LINQ to SQL in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C)

Hope it helps.